# Android wifi multi connection and control

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I have a project (control drone trough wifi from android tablet). Is it possible to do multi connection to 2 or 3 drones ? What type of connection must be? How should i make multi connection. Please who have information please tell me what to read about this topic (articles or books).
Thanks !   :)

Comment: Just run up WiFi Hotspot on Android tablet. Start listening server socket and on drones you should implement clients.

Comment: The problem is that i have to make a connection from tablet to drone not the reverse because i dont have possibility to programm them.

Comment: you are connecting to drone using P2P wifi connection? and each drone is flying AP?  Am i right?

Comment: This drones supports Wifi Direct/P2P. To connect to one im using P2P.

Comment: Yes it's possible, read this doc (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.00028.pdf). And try to find examples. And maybe this can help to you https://github.com/huangjay/multihops/tree/master/P2PWifiDirect/src/com/p2pwifidirect/connectionmanager

Comment: Thanks, will study this information!